# About modifying the content of an HTML file through php before loading the HTML file

Tags: php, html

Say for instance I want to go back to my main log in page which is all HTML/JS if the password/username fail to match when I run my PHP. I would like to be able to access my main login html page and make a div which contains an error message visible.

here are the code snippets to help with the example. Everything works fine, I just don't like it how all I can do is load the index page without telling my user what went wrong. I've been doing some googling but I haven't managed to get it right.

```
<?php //this is in a separate file "checklogin.php"
. 
. 
.

    if ($count == 1) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            header('Location: loggedin.php');
        }
         else {
            header('Location: index.php');
        }   
.
.
.
?>



<html> //separate file "index.php"
    <body>
    .
    .
    .

       <div id = "nomatch" name = "nomatch" style = "display:none">
         <p>
           username and password don't match
         </p>
       </div>
    .
    .
    .
    </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply add a parameter to your index.php redirect :

```
header('Location: index.php?error');
```

Your index.php becoming :

```
<?php if (isset ($_GET['error'])) { ?>
<div id = "nomatch" name = "nomatch" style = "display:none">
     <p>
       username and password don't match
     </p>
   </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Remember you will have to change the filename from index.html to index.php assuming it was originally called index.html, or the PHP interpreter wont get to run the new php code you have added to it.

Comment: Also safest to use full `<?php` as that will always work where `<?` may not if `short_tags` is turned off.

Answer (score 1):

There are about a 1000 different ways to do this. It all depends on how you are processing your login form. The simplest (but not necessarily best) way to do this is to return an error message attached to the URL.

For example, redirect to http://example.com?error=badpassword, then in your code you can retrieve it with:

```
Error: <?php echo 'error:' . $_GET["error"]; ?>.
```

More info here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp

EDIT: Basically the same as below... must have been submitted while I was typing my answer

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `index.html` by a `index.php` and pass URL variables when calling your `index.php` page, meaning :

index.php :

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['errors'])) {
    $errors = $_GET['errors'];
?>

<html>
    // some html tags
    <?php if($errors): ?>
        <div> your div error </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</html>
```

and call that file like this : `header('Location: index.php?error="what you want"');`